# How to copy a file to a pendrive in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, 18.04, server

What is the command to copy a file to a pendrive in Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: The same way you file copy to anywhere else. Where in the filesystem is your pendive mounted?

Answer (score 2):

When you insert your pendrive, it is automatically opened in the GUI. Press Ctrl+L in the file manager window to see the path where your pendrive is actually mounted (it will be usually `/media/username/label` where `username` is your username, and `label` is the label given to your pendrive when it was formatted). In the terminal, just copy files to this path using `cp` command: `cp filename.txt /media/username/label`.